# Is it possible to get the values of a called function at runtime?

Tags: python

For example:

```
def get_val(n):
    return n

def check_args(func):
    # gets the arguments of a function at runtime

get_val(1) 
get_val(2)
```

**Note**: This is probably bad practice, but I want to understand more about how python works.

Comment: So you just want `check_args` to be called automatically when `get_val` is called, without the caller needing to do it?

Comment: Perhaps wrap it with a decorator!

Answer (score 1):

Python decorators allow you to do this with minimal effort:

```
import functools

def check_args(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)  # Copies documentation and other stuff from wrapped func to wrapper, making it look as much like the wrapped func as possible
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff to inspect arguments
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@check_args
def get_val(n):
    return n
```

Using `@check_args` is equivalent to fully defining `get_val`, then doing:

```
get_val = check_args(get_val)
```

which means `get_val` gets replaced with the `wrapper` function, that now gets called first, can perform checks, then delegate to the wrapped function (in this case, `get_args`). Obviously, for just one function, it's kind of pointless (you could just put the checking in `get_val`), but if you want to check other functions, prefixing their definition with `@check_args` is a single line of code that doesn't get intermingled with the rest of the code, and keeps boilerplate down.